# Prototype String with Typescript

Tags: typescript

The following prototype method for a JavaScript String in Typescript 2.0.3:

```
interface String {
    splice(start: number, delCount: number, newSubStr: string): string;
}

String.prototype.splice = function(idx: number, rem: number, str: string): string {
    return this.slice(0, idx) + str + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem));
};
```

throws the error:

> error TS2339: Property 'splice' does not exist on type 'String'.

despite my interface. It seems to work fine in the playground. I am just running `tsc` on that file with no options. Why isn't this working?

Comment: I ran `tsc` (`2.0.3` and `1.8.10`) on a file containing only your code and it worked just fine. Are you sure that this is all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems to work fine in the playground.

That because you probably have an `import` / `export` in your file. Fix:

```
declare global {
    interface String {
        splice(start: number, delCount: number, newSubStr: string): string;
    }
}

String.prototype.splice = function(idx: number, rem: number, str: string): string {
    return this.slice(0, idx) + str + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem));
};
```

## More

This is covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html#modifying-native-types